# vb.net windows form connection excelworkbook

Tags: vb.net, navigation, windows-forms-designer

I'm creating a vb.net excellworkbook.xlsx file and worksheet from windowsform want to achieve. I could not. I do not make a connection between vb.net and windowsform. I need to use in my project, but dozens excelworkbook excelworkbook excel in the program I need to do without opening the windows forms and links to all the relevant supposed to do. I would be glad if you can help.

Comment: Maybe its me but this is not understandable.Better improve youre question.You used google translate?

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I have almost no clue what you're asking.  Almost no clue anyway.

Access, read and write an excel workbook in Visual Studio vb.net by doing the following:

Click Project > Add Reference > COM > Microsoft Excel  Object Library

In your code you will need:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
```

Then you can create the excel object:

```
Dim ExcelAp As New Excel.Application
```

Open a workbook:

```
Dim WrkBk As Excel.Workbook = ExcelAp.Workbooks.Open("Path")
```

And then access cells and their values:

```
WrkBk.Cells(1, 1).value = "Hello World!"
```

That might give you a start anyway.